# How to add native c++ code in Android project

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I  want to add c++ code into Android project . Can anyone help me ? I have searched into google, I got only how to communicate with JNI c++ code. But I need how to add a full c++ project into Android Studio ?

Comment: What do you mean by full c++ project? you can add c++ classes into android project here is the official explanation https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: i saw that , it shows only how to configure . Can you please give me a github project link where used c/c++ code ? It would better

Comment: check this
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

Comment: I am looking project not sample project

Comment: How is a "sample" project not a project?